# Why am I getting an "No maching processes were found" error upon executing this python file?

Tags: python, macos

I am working on a project in Python. Currently, only Option 1 works. (i just started this project) It goes through two levels of input and then runs a shell command that makes MacOS show a hidden file. But I am getting an error in the Macos Terminal upon running it: "No matching processes were found." Do you have any idea on why it could be doing this?

My code is too large to fit here, so here is a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/EuBJjge6

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os 

#function by popcnt on stackoverflow
def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name =='nt' else 'clear')

# thanks to No Spoko on StackOverflow for the original idea, what you see here is modified
def printLogo():
    f = open('logo.txt', 'r')
    logo = f.read()
    print(logo)
    f.close()

clear()

printLogo()

print('Welcome to Belowdeck! \n')

#some code ideas from stackoverflow, don't remember the user 
menuItem = {}

menuItem['1']="Show hidden files and folders"
menuItem['2']="Hide a file or folder from view"
menuItem['3']="Download files without a web browser"
menuItem['4']="List contents of a folder"
menuItem['5']="View any file's contents"
menuItem['6']="Change permissions of a file"
menuItem['7']="Restore a disk image to a device connected to your Mac"
menuItem['8']="Change the default screenshot location"
menuItem['9']="Change the default screenshot format"
menuItem['10']="Stop apps from syncing to iCloud by default"
menuItem['11']="Check for macOS updates every day instead of every month"
menuItem['12']="Enable a sound when your Mac connects to a power source"
menuItem['13']="Make holding down a key repeat characters"
menuItem['14']="Dull hidden apps in your Dock"
menuItem['15']="Hide non-active apps in your Dock"
menuItem['16']="Add a spacer to your Dock"
menuItem['17']="Change the delay before your Dock slides out"
menuItem['18']="Change the speed at which your Dock slides out"
menuItem['19']="Disable auto-restore in the Preview app"
menuItem['20']="Add a message to the login window"
menuItem['21']="Get rid of Dashboard"
menuItem['22']="Rebuild Spotlight"
menuItem['23']="Destroy your Mac \n"

options=menuItem.keys()
sorted(options)
for entry in options: 
  print (entry, menuItem[entry])

def option1():
    clear()
    print("Show hidden files and folders \n")
    selection1=input("Would you like to proceed with the operation? (y/n): ")
    if selection1 == "y" or selection1 == "Y":
        os.system("defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool TRUE && killall finder")
    else: 
        input('Invalid selection! ')
while True:        
    menuSelection=input("Please select your desired action:") 
    if menuSelection =='1':
        option1()
    elif menuSelection == '2': 
        print ("delete")
    elif menuSelection == '3':
        print ("find") 
    elif menuSelection == '4': 
        print ('4')
    else: 
        print ("Invalid action!")
```

[image]

Comment: "No matching processes were found." belongs to `killall finder`. Possibly no more `finder` processes running or you are not allowed to kill them.

Comment: don't use `f.close()` use context managers `with ... as ...:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a Mac, but Googling that error message throws up a lot of hits where people have had issues trying to kill processes. It's very likely that the issue is in line 59. Make sure the commands are correct. Also, avoid using `os.system()` call to execute shell commands -- it is not recommended. Use the subprocess module instead.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQxTSDh-ECk